# global variables in compile statement

Tags: compile

sorry for posting multiple questions about compile, but this is giving me some headache lately. This time my question is about using globally defined variables in a compile statement.

The problem is that when I define a compiled function that uses a global variable like this:

```
a = 1; (*global variable*)
GlobalVariableCompile = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, For[i = 1, i < n, i++, a + Cos[i*Pi] + Sin[i*Pi]]];
```

The function is way slower then the noncompiled version:

```
GlobalVariable[n_] := For[i = 1, i < n, i++, a + Cos[i*Pi] + Sin[i*Pi]];
```

which can be easily verified by calling for example:

```
AbsoluteTiming[GlobalVariableCompile[100000];]
AbsoluteTiming[GlobalVariable[100000];]
```

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

**My current solution**:
My solution right now is to define an additional parameter of the compiled function and pass the global variable `a`, then everything is very fast as expected (way faster than the noncompiled version):

```
GlobalVariableCompile = Compile[{{n, _Integer},{a, _Real}}, For[i = 1, i < n, i++, a + Cos[i*Pi] + Sin[i*Pi]]];
AbsoluteTiming[GlobalVariableCompile[100000,a];]
```

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate.  Did you search first?  Edit: I was probably thinking of [(31171)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31171/121) which is not the same.  Still looking for other relatives.

Comment: Could you describe how you intend to use your function?  For example will it be applied many times with the same `a` value?  If that is the case you could rebuild the compiled function when it is called.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't recall a question on localization of variables in `Compile`, except perhaps [the one by you](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/is-the-sharing-of-variables-in-module-block-within-compile-documented-behavior/), which is not exactly the same. It may be good to have a separate question discussing this, and what happens when the variables are not localized, and why.

Comment: @Leonid Yes, I believe I was mistaken about the duplicate unless it's on Stack Overflow.  I was hoping you'd show up to answer this as you're far better with `Compile` than I am.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'd like to, but I've been quite busy recently, and also now. Basically, upon a superficial look at the code, it is a matter of variable localization (using `Module` or `Block` inside `Compile`). If this is not done, those variables are considered global by Mathematica. They are then not compiled, and every time they are accessed, there is a call to the main evaluator, which is the reason for the slowness.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I intend to set the global variable `a` once and not change it over the whole course of the calculation. So basically `a` can be treated as a global constant.

Comment: See my answer for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function with argument `a` that returns a `CompiledFunction`:

```
mkCF[a_] := 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
   For[i = 1, i < n, i++, a + Cos[i*Pi] + Sin[i*Pi]]];
cf = mkCF[1];
AbsoluteTiming[cf[100000];]
```

Inspecting the `CompilePrint` reveals that there are calls to the evaluator:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
CompilePrint[cf]
```

which should be removed if you need performance. For example:

```
mkCF2[a_] := 
  Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, Do[a + Cos[i*Pi] + Sin[i*Pi], {i, n}]];
cf2 = mkCF2[1];
AbsoluteTiming[cf2[100000];]
```

There are no calls to the evaluator left:

```
CompilePrint[cf2]
```

As for performance:

```
AbsoluteTiming[r1 = GlobalVariable[100000];]
AbsoluteTiming[r2 = cf2[100000];]
(*
{1.009310, Null}
{0.054743, Null}
*)
```

and

```
r1 == r2
(*True*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was enlightening.

Answer (score 6):

Based on your comment:

> I intend to set the global variable `a` once and not change it over the whole course of the calculation. So basically `a` can be treated as a global constant.

I believe you merely need to inject the value of `a` and properly localize `i`.  These actions can be done with `With` and `Module` respectively:

```
a = 1;

With[{a = a},
 GlobalVariableCompile =
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
     Module[{i},
       For[i = 1, i < n, i++, a + Cos[i*Pi] + Sin[i*Pi]]
     ]
   ]
]
```

`With[{a = a}, body]` directly substitutes the global value of `a` for any explicit appearance of the Symbol `a` in `body`.  More significant to the speed of your code `Module[{i}, body]` defines `i` as a variable local to `Compile`.

ruebenko's use of `Do` fixes the second problem because `Do` uses `Block`-like scoping of its iterators, so they are already localized.