# Changeable global variables in compile statement

Tags: compile

If a global variable is changed before each call of the function then answer is not changed accordingly. Please see a toy example:

```
Clear[zIc];
With[{Aopt = Aopt},
  zIc = Compile[{{q, _Integer}},
                Aopt + q
                , CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
    ]];

Aopt = 1;
zIc[3]
Aopt = 3;
zIc[3]

(Debug) Out[203]=
6
(Debug) Out[205]=
6
```

Expected answers are `4` and `6`. I familiar with [31627](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31627/global-variables-in-compile-statement) and [78768](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78768/compile-global-variables-and-recursion) posts but theirs solutions don't help.

**[EDITED]**:

1. Removing `With` doesn't help also.
2. As it is very simple toy example it seems to be very obvious answer to pass global variable as an argument to the function but not in real code where `zIc` already has 7 arguments and `Aopt` is calculated 4 logical layers above.

Comment: The central goal of compilation is that you know in advance what goes in and what comes out. Having a global variable inside of compiled code like that would defeat the purpose of compilation. What you are asking for is simply not what compile was designed for or can be designed around. It will work if you don't compile to `C`, but it won't really give you tangible benefits.

Comment: Correction: for this to work, you need to remove the `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` option (which essentially bakes the current value of `Aopt` into the function).

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks for explanation of compiling mechanism. In my point of view compiling has significant leak of functionality. There is no possibility to use some kind of struct as an argument. So passing a lot of arguments to functions makes code poor readable. In other hand function decomposition breaks mathematic representation and makes code “C-like”. May be you could address me an idea or link to a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

By using `With`, you freeze the value of `Aopt` at compile time *if it has already a value assigned to it*. You may want to execute `Clear[Aopt]` before the compilation takes place.

Anyways, it is probably better to supply the value of `Aopt` as an argument to the compiled function. This makes things a lot more predictable and efficient as this removes `MainEvaluate` calls from the compiled function.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 3 ways you can go with this:

1. Include `Aopt` as an argument (Henrik's answer).
2. Include `Aopt` as a global variable without `"InlineExternalDefinitions"`. If you do this, the code compiled code will use `MainEvaluate`, which essentially stops the compiled code and makes it reach into normal WL evaluation to retrieve the value of `Aopt`. More often than not, this will kill off most of the benefits of compilation and if `Aopt` doesn't have a value that the compiled code can use it will be even worse than sub-optimal because the compile function will have to be completely abandoned and WL needs to resort to normal evaluation.

You can see this for yourself with `CompilePrint`:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
zIc = Compile[{{q, _Integer}}, Aopt + q]
CompilePrint[zIc]
```

3. Define a function that returns a compiled function with the value of `Aopt` "baked in". In this case, you treat `Aopt` as a parameter that doesn't change to often, so you can afford to make a new compiled function whenever it's value changes. Kind of like a just-in-time compilation.

This would look a bit like this:

```
ClearAll[zIc2];
zIc2[Aopt_?NumericQ] := zIc2[Aopt] = Compile[{{q, _Integer}}, Aopt + q]

Aopt = 1.;
cf = zIc2[Aopt];
cf[3]

Out[24]= 4.
```