# Usage of Block in Compile

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

When is there an advantage to using `Block` in `Compile`? For instance, if I have a multiple-step code, how do I decide which variable assignments I should put into the first argument of `Block[]`? Is it unwise to have functions being evaluated in there?

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19772/is-the-sharing-of-variables-in-module-block-within-compile-documented-behavior) for some germane details in *Leonid*'s answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Block` (or `Module`) is used for creating local variables in `Compile`.  (When used with `Compile` they're equivalent.)  You need to use them whenever you need to use any variables in compiled code.

#### Example

The following code does not localize `y`:

```
cf = Compile[{x},
  y = x*x;
  y*y
 ]
```

Since `y` is not localized to the body of `Compile`, it is treated as a global variable, and will trigger calling back to the main evaluator.  The practical consequence of this is that the program will run very slowly: the evaluation of `y`, or any assignments to `y`, will not be compiled.  The function will still work, but it will not be fast because only certain parts will be compiled.

[`CompilePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompilePrint.html) gives

```
1   V17 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, y = x x][ R0]]
2   R1 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, y][ R0]]
3   R2 = MainEvaluate[ Function[{x}, y][ R0]]
4   R1 = R1 * R2
5   Return
```

The correct way to write this is

```
cf = Compile[{x},
  Block[{y},
   y = x*x;
   y*y
   ]
  ]
```

Now `y` is localized and the function can be fully compiled, so it will run much faster.

```
1   R1 = R0 * R0
2   R2 = R1 * R1
3   Return
```

**Note:** It does not matter whether you use

```
Block[{var = 1},
  ...
]
```

or

```
Block[{var},
  var = 1;
  ...
]
```

They have the same effect.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new! How about function evaluation within the first argument of Block? Does it ever make sense to compile `Block[{a=SomeFunction[b],c=1},...]` with respect to `Block[{c=1},a=Somefunction[b];...]`?

Comment: @Ziofil It doesn't matter whether you have `SomeFunction[...]` or ` number there.  In your second example `a` is not localized, which will cause the performance problem I mentioned.